# Drag and Drop in a specific row of a grid in Genexus

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to use drag and drop in Genexus and I can drag an element from my grid to an external variable. Now I need to do the opposite, drag an external variable and drop it in a specific grid (free style grid) cell.

I tried to set

```
Event Grid1.Drop(&SDTDrag)
    &text = &SDTDrag.Turno
    msg("drop on " + &index.ToString())
Endevent
```

where &text and &index are on the grid

When I drop the object the index is always 1 (the first row of the grid), regardless of where I dropped it and it's always the first &text variable to be set

Since it's a Free Style Grid I also tried to put a Table inside it and use its drop event, but in this case the event is not even launched, like there is not a drop event linked to it

```
Event TableInternal.Drop(&SDTDrag)
    &text = &SDTDrag.Turno
    msg("drop on " + &index.ToString())
Endevent
```

Is it possible to do what I want here? Drag an element and drop it into a specific cell of a free style grid?